# Usuarios en aplicación multiempresa

Tags: genexus

```
GX17u6 
C#
```

Tengo una webapp que es multiempresa (multitenant) en mi lógica de negocios y ahora me interesa sea multiempresa en un único GAM, pero: **que cada empresa tenga usuarios independientes** (sus propios usuarios) de manera que: pueda tener usuarios locales con el mismo **username** en diferentes empresas. Aclaro que no quiero sea el mismo usuario que tiene permiso en distintas empresas.

Intenté crear este ambiente desde el **GAMManager** pero no logré tener usuarios propios en cada empresa. Cada vez que creaba un **repository** me "heredaba" los usuarios ya existentes, y quiero poder crear usuarios nuevos para cada repositorio con la posibilidad de eventualmente, repetir un **username** que exista en otro repositorio.

¿Es posible?

Gracias!

Comment: Excelente con eso funcionó, Gracias Chona!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que los repositorios tengan usuarios independientes, el "NameSpace" de los mismos debe ser diferente, simplemente haciendo eso ya resolvés el problema.